# When I create classes in model, does it automatically create database tables?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I just started learning about asp.net mvc. My previous expierence is in python django. I was wondering when I make classes in the models file, it will automatically create those tables for me? Sorry I am a real beginner.

Comment: It is not done automatically. You should visit this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/468777/Code-First-with-Entity-Framework-5-using-MVC4-and

Comment: Thanks for the answer shekhar. I thought asp.net mvc supports orm. So, why does not it create automatically?

Comment: ror is automatically, and asp.net mvc needs to add some plugins(ef or other orm)

Answer (score 0):

No, It just maps your input data and enables controllers to manipulate data and send to view. In order to fill data into database you should use `LINQ to SQL` and `data entity framework`.